# Specs2 how to test Give/When/Then style in a separate text file

Tags: specs2

I need a way to unit test a play scala project using Specs2's Given/When/Then style but the acceptances is written in the text file in like how it is in Jbehave.

Answer (score 0):

This use case is not supported at the moment. The idea behind specs2 is to leave the specifications in the hands of developers who are comfortable with coding (and version control).

With the GWT style in specs2 you can still write mostly text but it has to be inside a `Specification`. That being said you could definitely write your own trait which would extract this text from a totally independent file. But as far as I know, no one has done it yet.